# Export SQLite file in document directory via email

Tags: ios, sqlite, export, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to export a SQLite file via email located in the document directory when a user taps on the exportAllData button.  Using the code below, I was able to open up the mail app and attach a file.  However when I send it, the file does not get sent with the email.

```
- (IBAction)exportAllDataButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test@test.com",nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"SQLite File"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"This is your SQLite file" isHTML:NO];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mooddb.sql"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [composer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:path];
    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: plz chek mydata when you send may be it nil...???

Comment: It is working? I am getting empty data. Please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56151110/1635315 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was searching in the wrong directory.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

should be:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[composer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:path];
```

In FileName your are sending path...
So plz chege path to file Name..
LIke..

```
[composer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"mooddb.sql"];
```

Comment: This just changes the file name.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift version**

```
@IBAction func exportAllDataButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() == true else { return }

    let mailCompose = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailCompose.setSubject("Sqlite File")
    mailCompose.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

    if let documentsPathURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileName = "myDatabase.sqlite"
        let fullURL = documentsPathURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fullURL) {
            mailCompose.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "application/x-sqlite3", fileName: fileName)
        }
    }

    present(mailCompose, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```